# Why does the ReadLine () method NOT pause for user input?

Tags: c#, user-input, console.readline

I began to study C#, but I ran into a problem. The `ReadLine()` method does not pause for user input. I just started C#, and it works on other people's programs, so I have no idea why. I am using Xamarin on a Mac.

Here is an example code that does **not** work:

```
using System;

namespace LearningC
{
    public class LearningSharp
    {
        public static void Main (String[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (Console.ReadLine ());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I found out the solution. Right click on your project and select **Options**. Then, select **General** under the **Run** tab and check "Pause console output" ("Run on external console" must be checked for this to work.)

Comment: When my program finishes running it doesn't close that console. Is there a way to make it do that after the program finishes executing?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe your Project is set to be a Windows application. Right click on your Project name, click properties and change output type to Console Application.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem of a C# project not stopping with Console.ReadLine().

Here is my code:

```
char myChar1;
        string userName;
        string userLastname;

        Console.Write($"Insert a char: ");
        myChar1 = (char)Console.Read();

        Console.WriteLine($"Press ENTER to continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        Console.Write($"Insert name: ");
        userName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write($"Insert lastname: ");
        userLastname = Console.ReadLine();
     
        // More stuff here
```

I found that when I use the method Console.Read() the next method Console.ReadLine() does not stop at all.
So after inserting a char in the variable myChar1 the program goes forward and stops only after the method Console.Write($"Insert name: ");

The workaround is to place two Console.ReadLine() methods before the Console.Clear() one but I can not understand why this goes like that.